# Recursion problem with JPA and a Spring Rest Controller

Tags: json, spring-boot, rest, jpa, recursion

I have two JPA entities with a @ManyToMany relationship, for example *Student* and *Course*, something like that:

### Student Entity:

@ManyToMany

List<Course> courses;

### Course Entity:

@ManyToMany

List<Student> students;

What is the best way/pattern to implement a Spring REST controller which returns students and  courses? I would like to see inside the JSON Student the list of the courses enrolled, but stopping the recursion deep to the first level (to avoid a stack overflow). I would like the same for the JSON Course. In other words, I would like to see a student with a list of enrlolled courses inside, but do not want the list of students inside every course again, to avoid recursion. I know about @JsonBackReference an so on, but this is not the case because I want to see the lists in both the JSON's entities involved.

I know there are already some topics about this problem on stackoverflow, but I didn't find anything really definitive.

Could anybody give me some hints?

Best regards,

Bruno

Answer (score 0):

You can make projections to prevent the StackOverFlowError errors like:

```
public class StudentProjection {
   private String id;
   private String firstname;
   ..
   ..
   List<CourseProejction> courses;
   // getters and setters
}

public class CourseProjection {
   private String id;
   private String name;
   ..
   ..
   List<StudentProjection> students;
   // getters and setters
}
```

And for StudentRepository:

```
@Query("select new com.example.demo.projection.StudentProjection(s.id, s.firstname) from Student s left join s.courses c where c.name = ?1)
List<StudentProjection> findAllByCoursesIn_Name(String name);
```

With the query above, you will get list of the students with enrolled courses. Please correct me if i misunderstood the problem.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the best solution for this problem would be to make two different read models for each case, including its own endpoint.

This means that you would have a read model (and endpoint) for students with a list of their enrolled courses, and a *separate* read model for courses and their enrolled students.

There's no real reason why these two views should be coupled so tightly that they cause the problems that you describe, and so I would simply decouple them.

So, something like:

```
public class EnrolledStudent {
  String id;
  List<Course> courses;
  // ...
}

public class Course {
  String id;
  String name;
  Instructor instructor;
  // ...
}

public class CourseEnrollment {
  String id;
  List<Student> students;
  // ...
}

public class Student {
  String id;
  String firstName;
  // ...
}
```

while this does cause a bit of model bloat, it also forces you to think about the design of your API a lot more - note that I've called the third class above a `CourseEnrollment` - which is not necessarily a `Course`! Similarly, does a response containing Student *really* need to list *all* the fields of the courses that the student is enrolled in? Or would a subset of the data as a separate read-view suffice?

IMO this added model bloat is worth the design tradeoffs.

Comment: Thank you very much, yes I think decoupling the read models is the best solution, too. There are no reasons for tight coupling, as you said.

Answer (score 0):

You could try @JsonIgnoreProperties("field name") (where you would put @JsonManagedReference/@JsonBackReference), it will omit the field name so no recursion in json response...

But long term a DTO is a nice solution, since it would return that instead of the entity, so changes in entity won't break api that much.

Comment: Yes, but JsonBackReference and so on, would omit the field from my response.

Comment: You could make 4 DTO, studentinfodto, studentdetaileddto, courseinfodto, coursedetaileddto

Answer (score 0):

To handle the recursion issue you can make use of Jackson's `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` annotations. These annotations allow you to control the serialization and deserialization process to prevent infinite recursion.
Here is the example below how you can implement:

Student Entity

```
@Entity
public class Student {

    // Other fields and annotations
    
    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Course> courses;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Course Entity

```
@Entity
public class Course {

    // Other fields and annotations
    
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses")
    private List<Student> students;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

In the Student entity, we use `@JsonManagedReference` to mark the courses field. This indicates that the serialization of the courses list will be managed by the Student entity.

In the Course entity, we use `@JsonBackReference` to mark the students field. This indicates that the serialization of the students list will be handled by the opposite side of the relationship (i.e., the Student entity). This prevents the recursion issue by breaking the cycle.

Comment: Thank you, yes I knew about JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference, but in this way I won't see the list of students inside the course, which were one of my requirements.

Comment: you can consider using the @JsonIgnoreProperties annotation along with @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference like,
`public class Student {
    // Other fields and annotations
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JsonManagedReference
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("students")
    private List<Course> courses;
    
    // Getters and setters
}

public class Course {
    // Other fields and annotations
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JsonBackReference
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("courses")
    private List<Student> students;
    
    // Getters and setters
}
`

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).